# Applying taylor series: Given a 3-time differentiable function $f(x)$ at $x=0$, calculate $g(0),g'(0), g''(0)$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

> Problem: The function $f(x)$ is 3 times differentiable at $x=0$, with $3$-th order Taylor series approximation $g(x)$ around $0$. What are all the derivatives of $g(x)$ at $0$? I.e. calculate $g(0), g'(0), g''(0)$ and so on.

My thought process:

$g(x) = f(0) + f'(0)x + \frac{1}{2}f''(0)x^2 + \frac{1}{6}f^{(3)}(0)x^3$

Thus $g(0) = f(0)$

and $g'(0) = 2f'(0)$

and $g''(0) = 2f''(0)$ and so on

The correct answer:

$g(x) = f(0) + f'(0)x + \frac{1}{2}f''(0)x^2 + \frac{1}{6}f^{(3)}(0)x^3$ (So same as mine) [1]

$g'(x) = f'(0) + f''(0)x + \frac{1}{2}f^{(3)}(0)x^2$ [2]

$g''(x) = f''(0) + f^{(3)}(0)x $ [3]

thus $g(0)=f(0)$, $g'(0)=f'(0)$, $g''(0)=f''(0)$ and so on...

There are two things that I don't understand:

(1) In the differentiation of $g(x)$ ([2] above), why is $\frac{1}{6}f^{(3)}(0)x^3$ dropped? Is it because $f(x)$ is only 3 times differentiable and therefore $g(x)$ as well (why though?)

(2) Why did the differentiation of $f'(0)x$ become $f''(0)x$, as if we were treating $x$ as a constant? I thought we should apply $d(fg) = g df + f dg$, and therefore $f''(0)x + f'(0)$? (Hence my answer was $2f'(0)$ above when $x = 0$).

Thank you!

Comment: $x$ is not a constant but $f''(0)$ is.

Answer (score 1):

When working out this problem, keep in mind that $f^{(n)}(0)$ is a constant. Now looking back at the derivatives,
$$\frac{d}{dx}f(0)=0$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}f'(0)x=f'(0)$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{2}f''(0)x^2=f''(0)x$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{6}f^{(3)}(0)x^3=\frac{1}{2}f^{(3)}(0)x^2$$

So to answer your questions:

1. That term isn't dropped. It's just differentiated as specified by the derivatives I listed.
2. $f'(0)x$ did not become $f''(0)x$. It was $\frac{1}{2}f''(0)x^2$ that became $f''(0)x$.